# foldmarks steganography in koma-script

Tags: koma-script, steganography

I'm writing an `scrletter`.  I thought it could be fun to use `foldmarks` to encode a short message in the margin.

Has anyone seen a package or hack that does this?

Comment: What would such a message look like?

Comment: @Marijn Long and short foldmarks, corresponding to Morse's dashes and dots, could be nice.